# How to use $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Tags: php

I have used it as the following ways:

```
    print_r($_POST['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']);
    print_r($_POST['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']);
    $data = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
    print_r($data);
    print_r(file_get_contents('HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'));
```

But I am not getting anything even though am posting a json body as raw data.

Comment: Let me guess, on php 7+?

Comment: Be aware that `This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.6.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0.`

Comment: anything from php error reporting? and how are you accessing this as, `http://localhost`, hosted or as `file:///` directly into your browser? plus, what's the version of php here? edit: scratch the last part here; now we know.

Comment: Note that on php 5, only the 4th line would give you output, the rest is just plain wrong.

Comment: @jeroen *"only the 4th line would give you output"* well, they say they're not getting anything, so my above comment could have relevance. I said *"could"*  ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Ummmmm, sorry, my comment is completely unrelated to yours, it should have been directed at the OP...

Comment: @jeroen Oh, I know that :-) but the OP isn't responding here, they might think I'm nuts or something, or they just want *dah codez*; who knows.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Definitely not the first. Right?

Comment: @jeroen *heh!* definitely ;-) oh well... I think I'm going to go finish my coffee watching the sun come up... *yawn*.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Enjoy, I'll have mine watching the clouds :-)

Comment: @jeroen Cheers! oh, side note: I just voted to close.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'll second that motion.

Answer (score 3):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php):

> This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.6.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0.

You are probably using PHP 7 or greater which means this in unavailable to you. But, even if you are not, you should *not* be using code that is deprecated. Instead you should be using `php://input` as recommended.

From the top comment on that manual page:

```
<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
```

Comment: I am using php 5.5.9

Comment: More of a comment than an answer to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Raw input data supposed to be on `php://input` stream

```
<?php
$raw_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
```